# The name "class" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a class in the Dashboard.App_code

The functions in this class can be called without problem from the web form (bugs.aspx) to populate object data sources
But when I try to call a function from bugs.aspx.cs, I get the follwoing error message
**Compiler Error CS0103 The name 'Clmysql' does not exist in the current context**

**bugs.aspx.cs**

```
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    
    namespace Dashboard
    {
        public  partial class _Bugs : System.Web.UI.Page
        {       
            
             protected void Calendar2_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtdate2.Text = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            if (txtdate1.Text != "" && txtdate2.Text != "") 
                { 
                GridView1.DataBind();
                GridView2.DataBind();
                txtjson.Text = **Clmysql.GettreatedBugsdetails**(Calendar1.SelectedDate, Calendar2.SelectedDate);
            }
        }
   }
```

**app_codes\Clmysql.cs**

```
    using System.Data;
        using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
        using System;
        using System.Configuration;
        using Newtonsoft.Json;
        
        namespace Dashboard.App_code
        {
            public static class Clmysql
            {
                public static string GettreatedBugsdetails(DateTime Mydate1, DateTime Mydate2)
        {
            var conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mantis"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string StrQuery = "select *****mysql code here" max(date(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_modified))),realname";

            MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand(StrQuery, conn);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(Command))
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
            return  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
        }
}
}
```

**ASP.NET C# Web Forms Visual Studio 2019**

Comment: IIRC, code from `App_Code` gets compiled into one assembly, and the pages' code-behind gets compiled into a different assembly. The code-behind assembly references the `App_Code` assembly, not the other way around.

Comment: How to fix it ?

Comment: It's not clear to me from the code shown exactly how these two partial bits of code relate, or specifically what you're trying to use in any given context which doesn't exist in that context.  Can you provide a more complete demonstration of the code?  As an aside, if something other than a page is trying to invoke code on that page then that's *probably* the wrong design.  Have both components invoke logic in a shared location instead.  Any logic that's in a page class should be for just that page.

Comment: @KemalALGAZZAH Move the code you want to call into an `App_Code` class, and call it from both places.

Comment: Regarding the updated code... Where specifically is it looking for something called `identifier` or something called `class`?  Did you instead mean that the error says `Clmysql` doesn't exist in the current context?  If so then you probably just need a `using Dashboard.App_code;` directive.  The IDE should have a hint for this.  But it's not clear if that's exactly the problem since the question indicates two different error messages and the terminology from neither message is in the code shown.

Comment: it is Clmysql , I used teh Directive using Dashboard.App_code but did not fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching, I found the solution

Right-click on the class file "ClMysql.cs" => properties=>Build action: compile instead of content

Comment: Yes, i  fact, I now often do NOT use app_code. and the BIG reason why is app_code will be compiled by the web site. If  you use newer features of editor (Roslyn - free form text in code), then app_code stuff can fail. But, if you create your own folder say MyAppCode, and set it to compile, then you can be sure your compiling using your current setup - not what the web site decides to use. So, be careful - since code in app_code can often be attempted compiled by IIS after publishing - and you don't want that.  The better solution is to force (set) the build action to compile as you have.